# Adjust height of 2 elements in a div

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a paragraph and an image in one div and I am trying to adjust the top margin of the image so that it is a little bit higher on the page instead of the top of the image aligned with the top of the paragraph

---

```css
    #aboutmetext{
    font-family:avenir,calibri;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 5px black;
    width:45%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-top:0%;
    }

    #picture{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
    <div>
    <p id="aboutmetext"><b>I am a visual effects & motion graphics 
    artist with a Bachelor of Science degree from The Art Institute of 
    Pittsburgh. My focus is in motion graphics and graphic design.</b></p>
 <img src="http://moroccodunes.com/img/tours/14290060392.jpg" id="picture" class="bigEntrance" width="500px" 
    border="5" style="border-color:white;padding:5px">
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can give the [`image` a negative `margin`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) try this

```css
#aboutmetext{
    font-family:avenir,calibri;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 5px black;
    width:45%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-top:0%;
    }

    #picture{
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    margin-top:-50px;/* define the negative margin to your need */
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the title</h1>
<div>
    <p id="aboutmetext"><b>I am a visual effects & motion graphics 
    artist with a Bachelor of Science degree from The Art Institute of 
    Pittsburgh. My focus is in motion graphics and graphic design.</b></p>
 <img src="http://moroccodunes.com/img/tours/14290060392.jpg" id="picture" class="bigEntrance"
    border="5px" style="border-color:white;padding:5px">
    </div>
```